# Python Data Pipelines and Streaming

Tags: python, batch-processing

My work involves a lot of data processing and streaming and processing data from various sources often times a lot of data. I use Python for everything and was wondering what area of Python should I be researching in order to optimize and build batch processing pipelines? I know there are some open source variations like Luigi which Spotify has created but I'm thinking that is a little bit of overkill for me right now. The only thing I know so far is to study up on generators and lazy evaluations but was wondering what other concepts and libraries  I can use for efficient batch processing in python. One example scenario would be reading a ton of json formatted files and convert them into csv before populating into a database by using as little memory as possible. (I need to use SQL standard database as opposed to NoSQL). Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have much experience with databasing, but if you have to do large-scale mathematical computations, numpy certainly has some excellent features. When used correctly, you can get almost the same speed as a compiled language

Comment: You can always write your own modules. the place i work deals with a lot of data. However In our case we know the kind of data we get( only 3 formats). So we developed a small library with a lot of tools to handle it all. It took time but once it was completed it saved us a lot of time in future projects

Answer (score 1):

The example you mentioned, of reading lots of files, translating and then populating a database, reminds me of a signal processing application I wrote.

My application (http://github.com/vmlaker/sherlock)
processes large chunks of data (images) in parallel, taking advantage of multi-core CPUs. I used two modules to make a clean implementation: [MPipe](http://vmlaker.github.io/mpipe) for assembling the multi-stage concurrent pipeline, and [numpy-sharedmem](http://bitbucket.org/cleemesser/numpy-sharedmem) for sharing the NumPy arrays between processes.

If you're trying to maximize runtime performance, and have multiple cores available, you may be able to stage a similar workflow for the example you give:

**Read file** --> **Translate** --> **Update Database**

Reading the json files is I/O bound, but multiprocessing may get you speedups in the translation, as well as database updates.